# 'onclick' Storing Value Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, web-storage

so I have this `<a>` tag:

```
   <a href="/book-testdrive" class="addtocart" value="YX57WDL" title="Book Test Drive">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i>
     <span>&nbsp;Book Test Drive</span>
   </a>
```

As you can see it is given a value of `value="YX57WDL"` now what I would like to do is capture that value when the a tag is clicked and placed into a variable.

There are many `<a>` tags on my page with many different values that are created dynamically. If a user presses another a tag I'd like it storing in the same variable but replace the value with that of the unique `<a>` tag value.

Also the variable needs to be stored site wide, I guess the solution to this would be Web Storage API.

So far I've tried using this Javascript:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.addtocart ');

links.onclick = function(){
  localstorage['storedValue'] = this.value ;
}
```

However when I console.log() the links variable it contains nothing.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to wait until the DOM is loaded, or else the call to `document.querySelectorAll()` will not find anything if the element you are looking for has not been added to the DOM yet.

I see you added jquery as a tag, so I assume you are using jquery. If that is the case, you can wrap your code with the jquery function to wait for the DOM to be ready, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.addtocart ');

    links.onclick = function(){
        localStorage['storedValue'] = this.value ;
    }
});
```

Also if you are using jquery, you could be using its `on` function to make this a lot simpler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addtocart').on('click', function() {
        localStorage['storedValue'] = this.value;
    }
});
```

If you are not using jquery, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery) question about how to wait for the DOM to load without the jquery `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Edited to change `localstorage` to `localStorage`, as mentioned in the answer posted by @Stryner.

Comment: Hi seem to be getting a syntax error for both of these code examples, it's a little beyond my depth of knowledge to understand what is going wrong? I am using jQuery.

Comment: Oops, left off the `);` at the end. Updated the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelectorAll) returns a (non-live) node list. This means that it is basically an array, so you could do a loop for each one instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function(){
        localStorage['storedValue'] = this.value ;
    }
}
```

Also note that I changed `localstorage` to `localStorage` because it's case sensitive.

Comment: Hi I have tried adding this to the following page [Here](http://drivencarsales.co.uk/used-cars.html). If you try pressing the 'book test drive' A tag you will notice that the value isn't stored. I've added the JS to the end of the porto.js that you can see in the browser source file. Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Try ".getAttribute('value')" instead of ".value":

```
var links = document.querySelector('a.addtocart');

links.onclick = function(){
    localStorage['storedValue'] = links.getAttribute('value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".addtocart", function(e) {
    localstorage['storedValue'] = $(this).val();
});
```

You surely wonder why did your attempt fail. In fact, you were not too far from the solution, but you probably ran your script before your links were created. With the `.on()` function of jQuery you have a listener to the current and future elements matching the selector (which is `".addtocart"`).